# Why is this happening to my spider plant?

Tags: houseplants

[image]

The stems to my spider plant babies are have suddenly died!

What shall I do with the babies I don’t want them to die either?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If the stems are truly dead, then the only way you can save the spider "babies" is by potting them. It's best to plant them in 3 inch (5 cm) pots. These are relatively shallow as well - you don't want too much cold, wet soil around the roots this time of year (assuming you're in the Northern Hemisphere). You may already know this, but whenever you pot up plants or seedlings you must use sterilized soil-less potting "soil". It's best if the soil-less mix does not have any gels or additional fertilizer in it. Using this kind of mix prevents you and your plants from a ton of potential problems.

Once your little plants are established, you can fertilize with a relatively weak fertilizer meant for indoor plants (MiracleGro, for example). At that point, you can keep what you like and give the rest to your friends and relatives!

Comment: Wow thank you so much for all your advice, that’s great! Glad to hear I haven’t killed it ☺️

Answer (score 3):

The stems were originally flower stalks. They will die eventually. If you keep it in bright enough light (full sunlight is best), it will flower again next year and produce a new "family."

In  the wild, the babies touch the ground and start to grow as new plants. Plant half a dozen of the baby plants in one big pot, and as they grow it will look like one huge plant. Just cut the stem an inch away from the baby plant, and put it in the new pot just deep enough to stop it falling over till it starts to grow roots. A quarter of an inch deep is enough. Keep the soil surface damp until you can see they are growing (new leaves appearing in the center of the plant). Don't worry if the original leaves on the baby plant die off, so long as it is growing new ones.

The "guaranteed" way to get the babies to grow is imitate what happens in the wild, and make them touch the surface of some compost in a pot or a seed tray. You can hold the stem in position with a bit of wire (e.g. a paper clip) bent over like a staple and pushed into the soil in the pot. That works best *before* the stems have started to die, and the parent plant is still "feeding" them through them stems. But whichever way you do it, they are very easy to propagate.

Comment: Looks like you and I had the same idea... and timing :)

Comment: I once had a spider plant that was put in a store cupboard while the house was being redecorated, and got forgotten about. It was found about 3 years later, not surprisingly looking completely and utterly dead. Just for an experiment I cut off all the dead brown leaves, knocked most of the original bone dry compost off the roots, immersed it in a jar of water for 24 hours and then replanted it. Within a week it was growing as if nothing bad had ever happened to it! You have to try really hard to kill them - just about the only way that "works" is to over water them so much that the roots rot.